# Angularjs: img src disappearing when loading html from json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within a json element, let's say `data-html` I have

```
 <p><img src=\"images/wwgd.png\" alt=\"wwgd\" /></p>
```

Which I am rendering in the template using

```
 <div data-ng-bind-html="data-html"></div>
```

But the rendered output tag doesn't have the source, only the `alt` attribute:

(via inspect element in firefox):

```
  <p><img alt="wwgd"></img></p>
```

Comment: I found this comment: 'Additionally, a[href] and img[src] automatically sanitize their URLs and do not pass them through $sce.getTrusted. SCE doesn't play a role here.' On the $sce page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use angular strict contextural escaping `$sce`. Docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

Your example would look like:

Controller:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.myHTML = '<p><img src=\"images/wwgd.png\" alt=\"wwgd\" /></p>';  

    $scope.trustDodgyHTML = function(html) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    };
```

Page:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustDodgyHTML(myHTML)"></div>
```

This will explicity allow you to include this html here.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to `data-ng-bind-html` which I used in my question? It doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed - I think it's the use of $sce that will help you.

Comment: @CapsNZ I just noticed that introducting this function in the html, although making it work, introduces a lot of cryptic errors which are displayed in the console.

Comment: Can you post some of them? Despite the errors, this is definitely the way that you add dynamic html